# Passing a value back from ImageButton

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm just learning so probably doing this all wrong. I want to display multiple avatar images on the screen (75 when I suss this bit) and have the user select one. When they click one it calls procedure avatar_click which is where I need to recognise which one has been clicked.. But how do I do that ? I have this so far..

```
    <td><asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="Server" width="20px" ImageUrl="~/files/images/avatars/A01 copy.gif" OnClick="avatar_click" /></td>
    <td><asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="Server" width="20px" ImageUrl="~/files/images/avatars/A02 copy.gif" OnClick="avatar_click" /></td>
    <td><asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="Server" width="20px" ImageUrl="~/files/images/avatars/A03 copy.gif" OnClick="avatar_click" /></td>

Protected Sub avatar_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub
```

What do I need to put in the VB procedure avatar_click ?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: We can't say if you're doing something wrong if you don't write your code...  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I started trying to use a CASE staement or an IF statement but don't know how to pass a value back to the code from which image they click on. I thought it would be something easy like with DDL's where you can put value=1 etc then I could use SELECT CASE VALUE ?? Just don't know where to start. Sorry :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add CommandArgument to each button

```
<td><asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="Server" width="20px" ImageUrl="~/files/images/avatars/A01 copy.gif" CommandArgument="A01" OnClick="avatar_click" /></td>
<td><asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="Server" width="20px" ImageUrl="~/files/images/avatars/A02 copy.gif" CommandArgument="A02" OnClick="avatar_click" /></td>
<td><asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="Server" width="20px" ImageUrl="~/files/images/avatars/A03 copy.gif" CommandArgument="A03" OnClick="avatar_click" /></td>
```

In the button click, retrieve that CommandArgument

```
Protected Sub avatar_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   Dim btn As ImageButton = CType(sender, ImageButton)
   Dim buttonClickedValue As String = btn.CommandArgument
End Sub
```

Comment: Absolute superstar ! Thank you.. I've now added a SELECT CASE buttonClickedValue and it works perfectly. Can't thank you enough.

Comment: Any chance you can help me with this last part.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664881/setting-imageurl-using-a-filename-which-is-stored-as-a-string