# Setting ImageUrl using a filename which is stored as a string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to set an ImageUrl using a filename which is stored as a string. I'm getting no errors but there's just an empty picture box on the page. Any help is much appreciated.

ASPX..

```
<asp:Image ID="imgAvatar" width="80px" runat="server" />
```

VB..

```
imgAvatar.ImageUrl = (DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "avatarfilename").ToString)
```

I know the filename is stored correctly as it outputs to the screen when I do this..

```
Response.Write (DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "avatarfilename").ToString)
```

[image: Inspect Element - Empty image]

Comment: When you see the empty box, inspect the element, view the source and add that to your question so we can see what is being output.

Comment: Done that mate if you have any suggestions ? Thank you.

Comment: did you try changing ~files to ~/files

Answer (score 0):

In your Response.Write, you're referring to a different DataItem, "skypeUsername", whereas imageUrl gets its value from the DataItem "avatarfilename".

Comment: Sorry.. That was me changing it so it reads a little clearer for you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Can't believe it.. it has always worked !! Just realised, I missed a / out where I had the path saved in the data as ~files/ instead of ~/files/...

Answer (score 0):

You're outputting `"~files/[rest-of-file-path"`

That's not a valid path. The `"~"` means root, but the server has to render the full path.

You can try something like `Server.MapPath(path);` but you're missing the first `"/"` so you have the wrong path in your database.